# solr search in rails 3 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect(2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, solr

I've been trying to follow the instructions to install solr on rails 3 here:

https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot#readme

http://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2011/03/08/full-text-searching-with-solr-and-sunspot/

However, I can't seem to be able to get the search working on my rails server. I enter a query into the search bar and press enter, only to receive the error: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect(2)

The complaint seems to be coming from the "search" function in my model:

```
def search

  @posts = Post.search do
    keywords params[:query]
  end.results

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render :action => "index" }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @posts }
  end
end
```

The search bar looks like this:

```
<%= form_tag search_posts_path, :method => :get do %>
<p>
  <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query] %> <%= submit_tag "Search!" %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you run `bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start`? That error message is telling you that when you tried to search, you weren't able to connect to the Solr instance your app is expecting.

Comment: oh really, that's what the error means? unfortunately, i'm on windows, so mingw won't play well with "bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start". Instead, I had to run "bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:run". Do you think that might have caused a difference?

Comment: It shouldn't have, but that error message definitely makes it sound like your Solr instance isn't running. After you run that command - what do you get for output?

Comment: the command seems to execute fine initially -- it says "INFO: Logging to STDEERR via org...jetty-6.1.3...extract jar:file:/C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/sunspot_solr-1.3.3/webapps/solr.war!/ ... -- but then i get something that says "INFO: JNDI not configured for solr" and "No JMX servers found, not exposing Solr information with JMX. I'm not sure what it all means.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not sure either - sorry. :( After you see that error message, does the process keep running, or die?

Comment: :( the process continues running after those errors. it might also be worth noting that I get different errors when I don't use "bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:run" -- so it looks like that command is still doing something.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know enough about Solr on windows to be able to help out here - but it sounds like maybe this is a problem with your Java version after some quick googling. https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/issues/127 might help.